# Receive notifications during unit tests with XCTest?

Tags: unit-testing, xctest

In the old SenTestingKit we used to get some really useful notifications while the tests were running:

```
SenTestSuiteDidStartNotification
SenTestSuiteDidStopNotification
SenTestCaseDidStartNotification
SenTestCaseDidStopNotification
SenTestCaseDidFailNotification
```

These would also contain information about the tests/suites such as the name and failure description for failures.

These days, `XCTest` is the recommended way to do unit testing, I found that there was something called `XCTestObserver`, but it is already deprecated. So how can I monitor the progress of unit tests based on `XCTest`?

Answer (score -2):

This is one way to test the notification with mock http://www.hpique.com/2013/12/nsnotificationcenter-part-3/